# OSX Previewer with Emacs Editor: TeXShop, Skim, Adobe, Preview. updating and landscape

Tags: live-preview

So I am a dinosaur.  I use Emacs (and auctex), under OSX.  I run a unix background process that checks for file changes and reruns the pdflatex when it detects any.  it's very neat.  the previewer than updates it.  my focus remains on the editing window.  I can look left and right.

also, I am not perfectly happy with my preview apps.  I need a previewer that updates the view as soon as it detects that the pdffile itself has changed (and preferably does not change focus to itself).  this eliminated the adobe acrobat reader altogether.  it also eliminates the apple preview app, because it updates only on focus changes.  the TeXShop 3.52 build-in previewer seems nice, except that it does not seem to update, even if in the "TeXShop Preferences, I have "Automatic Preview Update" checked.  Besides, I would love to just use the previewer and lose the texshop editing window.

Skim.app seems to do the job best, except that it (1) still is struggling with up/down keys in single-page display mode; and (2) it thinks that when I want to view a rotated page, I also changed the file.  thus, it asks me whether I want to save the changes everytime I retypeset.  this is awkward.  (it would be even better if it recognized which pages are rotated and displayed them right.)

None of these solutions is smart enough to recognize that a {sidewaystable} page should be displayed in landscape, while ordinary pages should be in portrait.  not even sure if sidewaystable is the way to instruct the previewer about landscape pages in the pdf that should be displayed differently.

is there a better mousetrap here?

/iaw

Comment: Maybe you find more happiness if you move your preview app also into Emacs ;-)  Seriously, I'm not on OSX, but [pdf-tools for Emacs](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools) looks promising.  Watch for the features [here](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2bc1is_pdf-tools-tourdeforce_tech?forcedQuality%3Dhd720).  AUCTeX also has [support for it](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.auctex.general/5615).